# Loading XML to PIG : Error 2998

Tags: xml, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using `piggybank-0.12.0.jar`, and pig version is 0.12 (CDH)

```
pig --version

Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.3.2 (rexported)
```

I am trying to load xml file using `XMLLoader` of `piggybank jar`. During that getting below error:

```
REGISTER piggybank-0.12.0.jar;

DEFINE XMLLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader();

DEFINE RegexExtractAll org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.RegexExtractAll();

revisionXML = LOAD 'test3.xml' USING XMLLoader('Rev') AS (revision:chararray);
```

> Error: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled
>   internal error. Found interface
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

Any idea why it is coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution to above Error 2998.

To resolve it, either you can build the piggybank jar from source.
Link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank

In my case, I had used in built piggybank jar with CDH distribution (Since, I didn't had privilege to bypass proxy for online download). It worked fine for me.

Thanks,